# Flutter parsing multilevel JSON to a class using sound null safety

Tags: json, flutter, class, parsing, dart-null-safety

I use FLutter in Android studio, parsing multilevel JSON to a class. Although I have checked many stackoverflow post I can not find a solution for this problem.
This is my JSON

```
String myJson = '
[
 {
  "sensor":"1234",
  "data":
   [
    {
     "value":"40",
     "reading_time1":"2021-04-10"
    },
    {
     "value":"38",
     "reading_time1":"2021-04-11"
     }
   ]
 },
 {
  "sensor":"1235",
  "data":
   [
    {
     "value":"2",
     "reading_time1":"2021-04-23"
    },
    {
     "value":"39",
     "reading_time1":"2021-04-24"
    }
   ]
 }
] '
```

These are my classes, generated using https://javiercbk.github.io/json_to_dart/ . But the generated code did not work (not null safety) so after reading many post I came up with these:

```
class AllSensorData {

  String sensor="";
  List<Sensordata> sensordata = [];

  AllSensorData({required this.sensor,required this.sensordata});

  AllSensorData.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    sensor = json['sensor'];
    if (json['data'] != null) {
      sensordata = <Sensordata>[];
      json['data'].forEach((v) {
        sensordata.add(new Sensordata.fromJson(v));
      });
    }
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['sensor'] = this.sensor;
    if (this.sensordata != null) {
      data['data'] = this.sensordata.map((v) => v.toJson()).toList();
    }
    return data;
  }

}

class Sensordata {
  String value;
  String reading_time;

  Sensordata({
    required this.value,
    required this.reading_time
  });

  Sensordata.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) :
    value = json['value'],
    reading_time = json['reading_time1'];

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['value'] = this.value;
    data['reading_time'] = this.reading_time;
    return data;
  }
}
```

Now when I run:

```
var decodedJson = jsonDecode(myJson);
var jsonValue = AllSensorData.fromJson(decodedJson);
```

The error is:

```
type 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, dynamic>'
```

Although I suspect there might be more. Thanks for help.

Comment: decodedJson is actually a list of SensorData and not just one. You are trying to pass a list to AllSensorData.fromJson whereas it accepts a map and not a list. Hence the error. Try AllSensorData(decodedJson[0]) after ensuring there is at least one element in there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others have pointed out, the JSON has a list of sensor data, so you need to decode the list elements. I use [quicktype](https://app.quicktype.io/) to generate the (correct) code.

You say you are using `null safety`, but you do not have any optional data fields in your classes. If the fields in the data are optional, then you can use the `quicktype` option `Make all properties optional`. Unfortunately `quicktype` does not seem to know about null safety in `dart`, so you have to edit its generated code to add `?` on the data field declarations, and `!` on the references. I did this below:

```
import 'dart:convert';

List<Sensordata> sensordataFromJson(String str) =>
    List<Sensordata>.from(json.decode(str).map((x) => Sensordata.fromJson(x)));

String sensordataToJson(List<Sensordata> data) =>
    json.encode(List<dynamic>.from(data.map((x) => x.toJson())));

class Sensordata {
  Sensordata({
    this.sensor,
    this.data,
  });

  String? sensor;
  List<Datum>? data;

  factory Sensordata.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Sensordata(
        sensor: json["sensor"] == null ? null : json["sensor"],
        data: json["data"] == null
            ? null
            : List<Datum>.from(json["data"].map((x) => Datum.fromJson(x))),
      );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "sensor": sensor == null ? null : sensor,
        "data": data == null
            ? null
            : List<dynamic>.from(data!.map((x) => x.toJson())),
      };
}

class Datum {
  Datum({
    this.value,
    this.readingTime1,
  });

  String? value;
  DateTime? readingTime1;

  factory Datum.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Datum(
        value: json["value"] == null ? null : json["value"],
        readingTime1: json["reading_time1"] == null
            ? null
            : DateTime.parse(json["reading_time1"]),
      );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "value": value == null ? null : value,
        "reading_time1": readingTime1 == null
            ? null
            : "${readingTime1!.year.toString().padLeft(4, '0')}-${readingTime1!.month.toString().padLeft(2, '0')}-${readingTime1!.day.toString().padLeft(2, '0')}",
      };
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a slightly more generic answer for other people coming here.

### Analyzer options

When you have `implicit-dynamic` set to `false` in your **analysis_options.yaml** file, this can make it hard to parse JSON at first.

```yaml
analyzer:
  strong-mode:
    implicit-casts: false
    implicit-dynamic: false
```

### How to caste

If you are working with a list at the top level of your JSON, you can use `as List` to caste the type:

```dart
import 'dart:convert';

void main() {
  final myList = json.decode(myJson) as List;
  for (final item in myList) {
    final name = item['name'] as String? ?? '';
    final age = item['age'] as int? ?? 0;
  }
}

String myJson = '''
[
  {
    "name":"bob",
    "age":22
  },
  {
    "name":"mary",
    "age":35
  }
]
''';
```

That allows you to loop though each item. The `item` itself is `dynamic`, but you can still treat it as a `Map` and give it a default typed value if it is null.

### Using a `fromJson` method

Here is an example using a data class. (The import and `myJson` string are omitted for brevity.)

```dart
void main() {
  final myList = json.decode(myJson) as List;
  for (final item in myList) {
    if (item is! Map<String, dynamic>) return; //      <-- interesting part
    final person = Person.fromJson(item);
  }
}

class Person {
  final String name;
  final int age;

  Person(this.name, this.age);

  factory Person.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    final name = json['name'] as String? ?? '';
    final age = json['age'] as int? ?? 0;
    return Person(name, age);
  }
}
```

This one does mostly the same thing, except before passing the map into the `fromJson` method, you check the type. That allows Dart to safely promote the dynamic `item` to the `Map<String, dynamic>` type needed by the `fromJson` parameter.

Answer (score 1):

Your JSON data is a `List<dynamic>` hence `decodedJson` is also `List<dynamic>`.

You have to decode the json from each and every element of `decodedJson`.

```
  var decodedJson = jsonDecode(myJson);
  List<AllSensorData> list = [];
  for (Map<String, dynamic> json in decodedJson) {
    list.add(AllSensorData.fromJson(json));
  }
```

If you have any doubt comment it.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I tried to use the code, but during the runtime I get an error of: The following _TypeError was thrown while handling a gesture:
type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'String' debugging this line:  list.add(AllSensorData.fromJson(json));

Comment: This error occurs when one of the fields in the AllSensorData is given a value of null from the API. You need to check if any value is null or not in the fromJson method and return according to that.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is mostly correct. You just need to call `fromJson` **for each** element of `decodedJson` since it contains **many** sensorMaps not one.

```dart
List<Map<String,dynamic>> decodedJson = jsonDecode(myJson);

List<AllSensorData> sensorDataList = decodedJson.forEach(
  (sensorMap) => AllSensorData.fromJson(sensorMap)
);
```

You'll do the same for while calling `toJson`.

Comment: That's because in your class method fromJson you didn't specify a return type.